# Как перекодировать SSL-сертификат из формата PKCS#8 в формате RSA ( PKCS#1)

Tags: ssl, openssl

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как можно перекодировать SSL-сертификат из формата PKCS#8 в формате RSA ( PKCS#1). С помощью Certbot создал сертификаты для сайта, но на хостинге не принимают этот формат написали что нужно перекодировать в формат RSA ( PKCS#1). Дословно вот так написали "Панель управления принимает ключ в формате RSA ( PKCS#1). У Вас ключ в формате PKCS#8. Вам необходимо перекодировать ключ."

Comment: Что говорит гугл? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957742/how-to-convert-pkcs8-formatted-pem-private-key-to-the-traditional-format

Answer (score 0):

Короче, если кому-то поможет, проблема решается довольно просто:

Нужно во время создания сертификата в certbot поставить параметр формирования сертификата `--key-type rsa`, и он сразу сформирует нужный сертификат.

Общая строка запроса с подтверждением через DNS:

```
certbot certonly --manual --agree-tos --email ваш@gmail.com \
  --preferred-challenges=dns --key-type rsa -d вашсайт
```